# React typescript: Missing return type on function

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I am using React Typescript for my. I have created one React Context Api. The purpose of this context api is that user can change the language. I used translation package name [i18](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n-js). I followed this [Tutorial](https://lokalise.com/blog/react-native-localization/) to setup this i18. My app works fine. In the tutorial, the file was written in javascript but I am using Typescript for my app and I made some Es-lint rules.

The Translation Context Provider I am getting one Typescript error: `Missing return type on function`. I have tried lots of ways to silent the error But I could not able to do that.

**Here is code**

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import React, {createContext, useState} from 'react';
import LocalizedStrings from 'react-native-localization';
import * as RNLocalize from 'react-native-localize';

import en from '@local/translation/localization/en.json';
import ru from '@local/translation/localization/ru.json';
import fr from '@local/translation/localization/fr.json';

const DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 'en';
const APP_LANGUAGE = 'appLanguage';

const languages = {en, ru, fr};
const translations = new LocalizedStrings(languages);

interface localLizationContextType {
  translations: string;
  setAppLanguage: () => void;
  appLanguage: string;
  initializeAppLanguage: () => void;
}

export const LocalizationContext = createContext<localLizationContextType>({});

interface LocalizationProviderProps {
  children: JSX.Element;
}

export const LocalizationProvider = ({children}: LocalizationProviderProps) => { // Missing return type on function
  const [appLanguage, setAppLanguage] = useState<string>(DEFAULT_LANGUAGE);

  const setLanguage = (language: string) => {
    translations.setLanguage(language);
    setAppLanguage(language);
    AsyncStorage.setItem(APP_LANGUAGE, language);
  };

  const initializeAppLanguage = async () => {
    const currentLanguage = await AsyncStorage.getItem(APP_LANGUAGE);

    if (currentLanguage) {
      setLanguage(currentLanguage);
    } else {
      let localeCode = DEFAULT_LANGUAGE;
      const supportedLocaleCodes = translations.getAvailableLanguages();
      const phoneLocaleCodes = RNLocalize.getLocales().map(
        locale => locale.languageCode,
      );
      phoneLocaleCodes.some(code => {
        if (supportedLocaleCodes.includes(code)) {
          localeCode = code;
          return true;
        }
      });
      setLanguage(localeCode);
    }
  };
  return (
    <LocalizationContext.Provider
      value={{
        translations,
        setAppLanguage: setLanguage,
        appLanguage,
        initializeAppLanguage,
      }}>
      {children}
    </LocalizationContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: could you also add tsconfig.js file?

Comment: Can you tell us the complete error logs?

Comment: Can you hover on the `LocalizationProvider` in VSCode and tell us what the intellisense thinks it's datatype is?

Comment: I made a eslint rules and disable them: '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',. But I want to the real reason. This is my tsconfig setting https://codeshare.io/WdLdEW

Comment: Looks like TS cannot figure out the return type of `LocalizationProvider`, try specifying it explicitly (it'll be `JSX.Element`)

Comment: It's an eslint error, not a typescript error.